# For given 4 numbers as arguments of the function, I've to find the digit with max frequency combined for all numbers?

Tags: python, list, index-error, frequency-analysis, indexoutofrangeexception

Like for 1234,4566,654,987; we see, we have 4 and 6 both with 3 as frequency. So, we'll receive the output as 6 because it's the bigger one. 
So, the code which i thought as the solution is:

```
def MaxDigit(input1,input2,input3,input4):
    arr=[input1,input2,input3,input4]
    k=0
    for i in range(1,10):
        ask=[0]*i
    for j in range(0,4):
        while arr[j]!=0:
            k=int(arr[j]%10)
            arr[j]=int(arr[j]/10)
            ask[k]+=1
```

So, after this we'll get *ask* list with no.s as indexes and frequency with value. I can code that further.
But it is showing index out of range error for **last line i.e ask[k]+=1** which i'm unable to guess, why it's showing like that. Please help me with this.
If there could be an alternate code too, help me with it.

Comment: `no.s`???.......

Comment: It meant numbers.

Comment: I got the suitable code but can anyone tell me the reason why it was showing index out of range error in my code? @nick

Comment: @goodvibration can you tell me the reason behind index error in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
input = [234,4566,654,987]
digits = [int(n) for num in input for n in str(num)] # extracts each digit separately into a list as in [2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6, 5, 4, 9, 8, 7]
```

Generating a frequency dictionary and sorting the dictionary based on your conditions, first on the decreasing order of values, and then on the decreasing order or the key.

```
digit_count = {i:digits.count(i) for i in set(digits)} 
digit_count_sorted = sorted(digit_count.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], -x[0]))

digit_count_sorted[0][0] #prints the answer 6
```

You can implement it as a function :

```py
def MaxDigit(input):
    digits = [int(n) for num in input for n in str(num)]
    digit_count = {i:digits.count(i) for i in set(digits)} 
    digit_count_sorted = sorted(digit_count.items(), key=lambda x: (-x[1], -x[0]))
    return digit_count_sorted[0][0]

print(MaxDigit([234,4566,654,987])
```

Output :

```
6
```

Comment: I had thought of dictionary approach but couldn't implement it. It worked.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this is with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=collections%20counter#collections.Counter), converting all the numbers to strings and counting the digits. You can then find the maximum count from the counter and return the largest value that has that count:

```
from collections import Counter

def MaxDigit(*args):
    counts = Counter(''.join(str(a) for a in args))
    maxcount = counts.most_common(1)[0][1]
    return int(max(v for v, c in counts.items() if c == maxcount))

print(MaxDigit(1234,4566,654,987))
```

Output:

```
6
```

As an alternative to finding the maximum count and filtering on that, you can sort the `Counter` descending on count and then key and then return the key of the first value:

```
def MaxDigit(*args):
    counts = Counter(''.join(str(a) for a in args))
    counts = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x:(-x[1], -int(x[0])))
    return int(counts[0][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def MaxDigit(input1,input2,input3,input4):
    s = '{}{}{}{}'.format(input1,input2,input3,input4)
    maxCount = 0
    maxDigit = 0
    for digit in range(10):
        count = s.count(str(digit))
        if maxCount <= count:
            maxCount = count
            maxDigit = digit
    return maxDigit
```